# Where does the `jupyter` command comes from on OSX

Tags: python, pip, jupyter, setuptools

I reinstalled `jupyter` on my mac today and found that jupyter command is not found.

```
$ jupyter
zsh: command not found: jupyter
```

Searched my python(installed by `Homebrew`) bin directory, not `jupyter` there.

So I checked the package info:

```
$ pip3 show -f jupyter
Name: jupyter
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: Jupyter metapackage. Install all the Jupyter components in one go.
Home-page: http://jupyter.org
Author: Jupyter Development Team
Author-email: jupyter@googlegroups.org
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: notebook, ipywidgets, jupyter-console, ipykernel, qtconsole, nbconvert
Required-by:
Files:
  __pycache__/jupyter.cpython-37.pyc
  jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
  jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/INSTALLER
  jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/METADATA
  jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/RECORD
  jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/WHEEL
  jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/metadata.json
  jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/pbr.json
  jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
  jupyter.py
```

nothing like `../../../bin/jupyter` here.

But I'm sure I can got `%python_root%/scripts/jupyter` on my windows PC with the same wheel package.

So where dose the `jupyter` command comes from and how can I fix that.

Comment: It moved to `jupyter-core` now, try `pip3 show -f jupyter-core`

Comment: How did you install Jupyter ?

Comment: @hoefling, yes! That's the problem, `../../../bin/jupyter` is listed here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @hoefling.

`pip uninstall jupyter && pip install jupyter` did nothing.

The `jupyter` command in `bin` folder is provided by `jupyter-core` package.

So if there is something wrong with your `jupyter` package, reinstall all packages started with `jupyter` is much better than just reinstall `jupyter`.